# What is the website Mathilda is viewing in the first episode of Humans?

Tags: humans

What is the website Mathilda is watching in the first episode of Humans?

[image]

Is it an existing website?

I couldn't find it using Google, hoping someone recognizes the site.

Answer (score 3):

It is most likely non-existing.

In my experience websites used in movies or TV shows are non-existent, or if they exist they're "fake", i.e. specifically developed to target the viewers, as some sort of promotional tool. This happens [for various reasons](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/04/17/silicon-valley-fake-websites-tv):

> Some TV shows make up websites to skirt copyright issues. Others use
>   fictional sites as plot devices.

The main problem with using an existing website is that its owners have to give permission; the same is true for brands of food, cars, etc. so writers are instructed to avoid existing brands.

Comment: Yep. I remember working on a show and they had a fake Facebook site but they actually *bought* the domain so they didn't have to worry about legal issues.